# Minecraft realm not showing up in singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have a realm that has run out of time, but I had it in single player, and now it won't show up. It is still in saves, and in the folder in still has `level.dat` and the region folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "has run out of time"? Your subscription has lapsed?

Comment: But if i do that i will lose all the things i built in the singleplayer world

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should be able to export your realm even if your subscription has shortly ended. Maybe you try a re-download and use it again.

You can read more about it in the [Realm FAQ](https://minecraft.net/realms/faq).

> **Can I export my Minecraft map from Realms?**
>
> You can export your maps at any time, even for a limited duration after your subscription has expired.